# Selecionando um item do SELECT HTML

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando deixa o item selecionado o que tem o `id` igual ao do `$_REQUEST`

```
$combo .= "<option value='".$row_area->area_id."' ".if($id == $row_area->area_id) { echo "selected"; } .">".$row_area->are_descricao."</option>";
```

Mas só que esta exibindo esse erro:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`, o código completo está assim:

```
for($j = 0; $j < $table_area->RowCount(); $j++) {
    $row_area = $table_area->getRow($j);
    $combo .= "<option value='".$row_area->area_id."' ".if($id == $row_area->area_id) { echo "selected"; } .">".$row_area->are_descricao."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz isso com um ternário, senão estás a colocar um `echo` dentro de uma concatenação de string e o echo vai sair primeiro, sozinho. Na verdade acho que essa sintaxe nem iria passar mas de qq maneira a maneira correta seria:

```
$selected = $id == $row_area->area_id ? "selected" : "";
$combo .= "<option value='".$row_area->area_id."' ".$selected.">".$row_area->are_descricao."</option>";
```

Outra variante, correta mas no meu ver menos limpa:

```
$combo .= "<option value='".$row_area->area_id."' ".($id == $row_area->area_id ? "selected" : "").">".$row_area->are_descricao."</option>";
```